# Part Identification: Black Bionicle Foot Piece?

Tags: part-identification

[image: Foot Piece]

I saw this piece used as a foot in someone's MOC and I can't figure out what it is. It kind of looks like a Bionicle foot but it doesn't match any that I know of. Pretty sure that the axle going through it in the picture is separate and not part of the piece. Can anyone help me identify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a ["Sports Hockey Skate"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44847) mostly from LEGO Hockey although it has appeared in some BIONICLE sets also.

[image]